# Resolution stuck at 640x480 after trying to install NVIDA drivers

Tags: linux, linux-mint, resolution, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

The fans on my Clevo W230ST haven't stopped blowing since I installed Mint. I thought the video card drivers might be at fault so I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

On restart, the resolution was set to 640x480 and I haven't been able to figure out how to change it back. The display settings don't have any any other selectable options and nothing else I've done (purging/reinstalling nvidia programs, deleting `xorg.conf`, changing the refresh rate in `xorg.conf`, and re-installing `xserver-xorg`.

I don't think drivers are actually installed. `Driver Manager` says there aren't any proprietary drivers and `nvidia-settings` tells me to "run nvidia-xconfig as root" even after I've just done so.

Comment: That thing has an nVidia Optimus thingy thing...[you're in for a fun ride](http://bumblebee-project.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think bumblebee managed to install itself correctly either, when I try to run a program with it I get `[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0`

Answer (score 0):

please paste here what `lspci` says about the graphics

you may need to update pciids - `sudo update-pciids` before.

usually the problem appears if nvidia kernel driver is not compiled for some reason.

you can check it by running `modprobe nvidia` or `modprobe nvidia-current`
and see if is loaded with `lsmod` or not.

also could be that nvidia-current doesn't support your graphics card.
there are nvidia-legacy-* packages for cards not supported by nvidia-current package.